# Transpose fail in 11.1 Dataset

Tags: dataset, associations, query

The type system underlying Dataset seems a total kludge, as soon as one issue is fixed, here it recurs in a slightly different form - and difficult to isolate in minimal examples.

Here's a failure of Transpose in 11.1. Given this Dataset which has to be saved and imported as an .mx file otherwise copy/pasting its content into a new Dataset will not reproduce the error:

```
ds = Import["http://statigrafix.com/stackexchange/ds-transpose-issue.mx"]
```

[image]

This fails:

```
ds [All, Transpose]
```

> Failure[[WarningSign]    Message:    The first two levels of _Association
>   cannot be transposed. Tag:    Transpose ]

But normalizing and or reforming a new dataset (after normal) shows that it works:

```
ds // Normal // Query[All, Transpose] // Dataset
```

and

```
ds // Normal // Dataset //  Query[All, Transpose]
```

yield:

[image]

Comment: Somehow your Dataset is broken. Try `(ds // Normal // Dataset)[All, Transpose]` and see that it works. Your last line of code shows this as well as you do merely more that recreating the dataset. One hint is that the display of your dataset is not correct. You shouldn't see the raw Associations.

Comment: @halirutan, it's not broken. the Dataset I saved is exactly what is imported - that's my point, once you cycle through // Normal // Dataset it works - the type system is reset. Also, that's how the dataset renders (Associations), - albeit I am only using a slice as it is proprietary data.

Comment: If the dataset you saved looked exactly like [your first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N542P.png) it was already messed up. An Association of this structure should display differently, like your last screenshot but transposed. You question should rather be "what happened to my dataset and when?" because `Transpose` only fails because the dataset is internally incorrect.

Comment: @halirutan, you are completely off on this issue - *should* is different than *is*. Why do you think I saved it as .mx instead of copy/pastying it as an Association (source code) and the wrapping Dataset around it?

Comment: The workaround is `ds[All, (Transpose@# &)]`.I have seen some strange `Transpose` behaviour as well.  Think it has to do with the *syntax sugar* of `Transpose` in `Dataset`s.  Using a pure function hides `Transpose` from the *syntax sugar* and lets it just transpose the `Association` passed to it.  Could be some sort of `UpValue` on `Transpose` in `Dataset` doing this.

Comment: @alancalvitti Look at the end of WReach's answer. He tried to guess what went wrong in creating your dataset.

Comment: @halirutan, I read his answer  -  same as I gave you, there's nothing wrong with the data or operations in it, there is something wrong with the type inference system, hence my Q here. Why don't you normalize the imported dataset and tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: This is my point. Your question is not about how or why your association types got confused. Your title says why `Transpose` fails, which is only the result, but not the cause of the underlying problem. When you *type* your associations in code and wrap dataset around it, the issue does not appear. So the messed up type inference seems to be related to some operation you did on the dataset. If you find the step, that confused the type system, you have a starting point for a bug-report. Otherwise, you are left with workarounds that do not fix the underlying issue.

Comment: @halirutan, I filed a bug-report. And the issue only appears upon application of Transpose. If Transpose is not involved, the underlying Dataset is fine (save for 100k other issues).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As observed in the question, the problem lies with the type information of the dataset.  Specifically, the type information for the innermost association is missing (i.e. "any type").  This causes the operator `Query[Transpose]` to fail as the type system prohibits attempting to transpose an association with an arbitrary expression.

**Work-arounds**

As noted in the question, one work-around is to force the type information to be regenerated by type-deduction before querying.  Here is a succinct way to do that:

```
ds[Dataset][All, Transpose]
```

Another work-around is to use the "regular" `Transpose` function instead of the `Transpose` query operator:

```
ds[All, Transpose[#]&]
```

The second work-around is brittle, but the first will cure most(?) type-inferencing errors.

Also see the definition of `untypedDataset` near the end of this response which bypasses dataset type-checking.

**Analysis (current as of version 11.1.0)**

Let us inspect the data type of the dataset:

```
Needs["Dataset`"]
Needs["TypeSystem`"]

ds // GetType
(* Assoc[Atom[String], Assoc[Atom[String], AnyType, AnyLength], AnyLength] *)
```

The type tells us that:

- The top-level element is an association that maps strings to associations.
- The level one element is an association that maps strings to *AnyType*.

It is this *AnyType* that causes the problem.  The type-inferencer will reject the application of the `Transpose` query operator to this type:

```
TypeApply[Query[Transpose], {Assoc[Atom[String], AnyType, AnyLength]}]
(* FailureType[...] *)
```

*Transpose Function Work-around*

On the other hand, it will permit the regular `Transpose` function to be applied:

```
TypeApply[Transpose, {Assoc[Atom[String], AnyType, AnyLength]}]
(* UnknownType *)
```

It is not sure what to make of the operation, but it does not reject it.  This difference is explained by the type signatures of the two operations:

```
Signatures[Query[Transpose]]
```

[image: transpose operator signatures]

```
Signatures[Transpose]
(* --- none --- *)
```

We can see that the `Transpose` *operator* will accept an association whose values are structures, tuples, vectors or associations... but any other value types will fail (see the `FailureType` entry for type `t_` further down the list).  The `Transpose` *function* has no type signatures at all, so anything goes.

This explains why the work-around using the `Transpose` *function* gives us a result.

*Type Deduction Work-around*

The first work-around is less mysterious.  The type-deducer does a much better job of generating type information than the type-inferencer.  So we can fix up the type information by forcing a type rescan:

```
ds[Dataset] // GetType

(* Assoc[Atom[String]
   , Struct[{"history", "future"}
     , { Assoc[Atom[Enumeration["Adjustment", "Balance", ...]], Atom[Real], 6]
       , Assoc[Atom[Enumeration["Adjustment", "Balance", ...]],  Atom[Real], 6]
       }
     ]
   , 2
   ] *)
```

We now have the full type information.  Levels one and two are now a structure containing associations.  If we look again at the signatures for the `Transpose` operator, we see that this is a permissible combination.  Indeed, the query now works:

```
ds[Dataset][All, Transpose]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

*Missing Type Information?*

So how did the type information get messed up in the first place?  The internal structure of `ds` shows us that this dataset was generated by applying the following query to some other dataset:

```
Query[1, 1, 1, 60, (1 ;; 2) /* KeyMap[Function[expr, StringTake[expr, -4]]], "eventTotals"]
```

The source dataset is not included in the *mx* file.  When the type inferencer applied this query to the original data, it was unable to compute the full type information.  We got "watered down" information instead, where the inner associations were identified as *AnyType*.

*General Strategy*

To avoid these problems, I tend to avoid wrapping data in `Dataset` and use constructions like `rawData // Query[...]` instead.  But, if I am using datasets, I often force the type information to be rebuilt by adding a trailing top-level `Dataset` operator, e.g.

```
myDataset[someOps /* Dataset, moreOps]
```

This way, the dataset has the best available type information and downstream queries do not have to worry about it.

**Untyped Datasets?**

`Dataset` provides three main services: type-checking, data visualization and an abbreviated syntax for chaining applications of `Query`.  If we want to dispense with type-checking but retain the other features, we could write our own convenience wrapper.  Here is a sketch implementation:

```
untypedDataset[ds_Dataset] := untypedDataset[ds // Normal]
untypedDataset[data_][queryOps___] := untypedDataset[data // Query[queryOps]]
Format[untypedDataset[data_]] := data // Dataset
```

So then:

```
utds = untypedDataset[ds]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

```
utds[All, Transpose]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

```
utds[All, Transpose]["b685"][All, "future"][{"Balance", "Charge"}]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Comment: Very informative (+1).  I always thought it had something to do with special rules (a.k.a syntax sugar) for `Transpose` but had no clue how to investigate it.

Comment: @WReach, " I tend to avoid wrapping data in Dataset" - in other words, you don't use Dataset?

Comment: @WReach, by the way, same error without the KeyMap[Function...] - that's just to mask the account numbers. The rest is just routine projections of datasets. The real Q is why does the type system not understand it while inside Dataset, but gets it after // Normal // Dataset ?

Comment: @alancalvitti I only use `Dataset` as a terminal visualization tool similar, say, to using `MatrixForm`.  So I operate upon the raw data stored in variables and only at the very end visualize the result with `Dataset`.  The answer to the "real Q" is that the type inferencer (invoked by query applications) gets different answers than the type deducer (invoked by dataset construction).

Comment: @WReach, understood - but the ds[query1][query2]...[queryn] syntax is too convenient and about ~1/2 the time, the rendering is ok. Try working with deeply nested Associations, eg 6-8 levels, without Dataset.

Comment: @alancalvitti See the new section in my response: _Untyped Datasets?_.

Comment: I wish I could (+1) again for `untypedDataset`.

Comment: @WReach, thanks for the in-depth analysis as always. Your key phrase that it's the Query version that fails led me to use the non-operator form `(Transpose[#] &)` - where parentheses typically needed with RightComposition.